# How the correct way to resize image size in php doc

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to create a .doc file using php that has image inside it. 
The image inside it has a quite big weight and height, but i want to include it without creating a new small version image of it.

Here is my code

```
<?php
    set_time_limit (0);
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=test.doc");    
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Windows-1252">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="http://localhost/test_zip/img/jesse_what.png" style="max-width:50; width:50;max-height:50; height:50;">
    </body>
</html>
```

How is the correct way to resize it? because the style i place in the image tags is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while of searching, i found a way to do it.
So I add width and heigh attributes to the img tag

now it looks like this

```
<img src="http://localhost/test_zip/img/jesse_what.png" width="160" height="200">
```

Answer (score 1):

Put `px` and remove `max-width:50` and `max-height:50`

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Windows-1252">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="http://localhost/test_zip/img/jesse_what.png" style="width:50px; height:50px;">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: still not working, here is the result
http://s14.postimg.org/ov3xaey01/result.png